# Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a ring $R$. Show that there exists a subring $R'$ of $R$ that contains $S$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation

I am kind of stuck on how to prove this. I thought maybe cases would work?

> Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a ring $R$. Show that there exists a subring $R'$ of $R$ that contains $S$.

Case 1: $S$ is a ring, so $R'=S$.

Case 2: $S$ is not a ring, so construct $R'$ to contain $S$ and elements needed to be a subring of $R$.

This is what my only idea is so far. Is there any easier or better way to prove this?

Comment: What about R'=R ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is a subring of itself so you can always let $R' = R$. If you mean for $R'$ to be a proper subring of $R$ then the claim is not true. For a counterexample, let $S = \mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. Then the only subring of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $S$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ itself.

Comment: Hello, thank you for taking the time to reply. The question does not say that $R'$ is proper, just to prove that there exists any subring $R'$ that contains $S$.

Comment: Yes, then in that case just note that $R$ is such a subring in all cases, because $R$ is obviously a subring of itself and it will necessarily contain $S$. There really isn't anything else that needs to be said.

Comment: Thank you, you're very smart! I didn't even think of this simple case at all, I guess the question really spooked me.

Comment: Indeed, it does seem like almost a trick question.